# Why is my program only doing the else statement on one of the if statements

Tags: java

I want my code to make sure that all the if statements work, and if one of them doesn't work, it should put that that specific one is incorrect and not show the IP address part. right now when I'm doing it, it only works on the 4th one. the other ones say that it is incorrect but still put the IP address.

```java
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter the first octet:");
    int a = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter the second octet:");
    int b = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter the third octet:");
    int c = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter the fourth octet:");
    int d = scan.nextInt();

    if (!(a >= 0 && a <= 255))
    {
        System.out.println("Octet 1 is incorrect");
    }
    if (!(b >= 0 && b <= 255))
    {
        System.out.println("Octet 2 is incorrect");
    }
    if (!(c >= 0 && c <= 255))
    {
        System.out.println("Octet 3 is incorrect");
    }
    if (!(d >= 0 && d <= 255))
    {
        System.out.println("Octet 4 is incorrect");
    }

    else
    {
        System.out.println("IP Address:" + a + "." + b + "." + c + "." + d);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a helper variable `bool valid=true;` which you set to `false` inside your `if()` statements. After that, check with `if (valid) {...}` if the validation was successful or failed.

Answer (score 2):

An else statement can always only belong to one if condition.

I assume you want to verify all ip address octets and print a message if one of them is not in the valid range. Only in the case that the adress is valid it should be printed (your current else directive).

I would suggest creating a boolean variable before running the checks. This boolean will tell if all four octets are correct.

```
boolean allOctetsValid = true;
if (!(a >= 0 && a <= 255))
{
    System.out.println("Octet 1 is incorrect");
    allOctetsValid = false;
}
if (!(b >= 0 && b <= 255))
{
    System.out.println("Octet 2 is incorrect");
    allOctetsValid = false;
}
if (!(c >= 0 && c <= 255))
{
    System.out.println("Octet 3 is incorrect");
    allOctetsValid = false;
}
if (!(d >= 0 && d <= 255))
{
    System.out.println("Octet 4 is incorrect");
    allOctetsValid = false;
}

if(allOctetsValid)
{
    System.out.println("IP Address:" + a + "." + b + "." + c + "." + d);
}
```

This is only one possible solution.

**Additional improvements:**

The actual conditions could be simplified `!(d >= 0 && d <= 255)` can also be written as `0 <= d && d <= 255`.

Consider creating a method that returns if an octet is valid isntead of duplicating the condition four times. Example:

```
private boolean isValidOctet(int octet)
{
    return 0 <= octet && octet <= 255;
}
```